# What is the Elasticsearch-py equivalent to alias actions?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to implement [multiples indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multiple-indices.html#multiple-indices) approach using [elasticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). There are basically two steps:

**1. Create aliases:**

```
PUT /tweets_1/_alias/tweets_search 
PUT /tweets_1/_alias/tweets_index
```

**2. Change alias when necessary:**

```
POST /_aliases
{
  "actions": [
    { "add":    { "index": "tweets_2", "alias": "tweets_search" }}, 
    { "remove": { "index": "tweets_1", "alias": "tweets_index"  }}, 
    { "add":    { "index": "tweets_2", "alias": "tweets_index"  }}  
  ]
}
```

I could only implement the step 1 using [elasticsearch-py](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) (not the dsl):

```
from elasticsearch.client import IndicesClient
IndicesClient(client).("tweets_1", "tweets_search")
IndicesClient(client).("tweets_1", "tweets_index")
```

I have no clue how to do that for step 2. So, what would be the equivalent in elasticsearch-dsl (or at least in elasticsearch-py)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To implement that you need to use `elasticsearch-py`:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

# use es.indices instead of instantiating IndicesClient
es.indices.put_alias(index='tweets_1', name='tweets_search')
es.indices.put_alias(index='tweets_1', name='tweets_index')

es.indices.update_aliases({
  "actions": [
    { "add":    { "index": "tweets_2", "alias": "tweets_search" }}, 
    { "remove": { "index": "tweets_1", "alias": "tweets_index"  }}, 
    { "add":    { "index": "tweets_2", "alias": "tweets_index"  }}  
  ]
})
```

Comment: Does the update_alias no longer accept "actions"? This response makes sense, but is not working.

Comment: Are you sure you're using version 8? In the [8.11 python api it's actions](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/8.11/elasticsearch/_sync/client/indices.py#L3918), but in [v7 it's body](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/7.17/elasticsearch/client/indices.py#L652) despite the fact that the web api didn't change in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

```
index_list_for_realias = [...]
aliases_list_to_realias = [...]

for i in index_list_for_realias:
    print(i)
    for j in aliases_list_to_realias:
        es.indices.put_alias(index=i, name="logstash5-uni-" + j, body={
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "uni": j
                    }
                }
            }
        )
```