# Elasticsearch python create alias from json

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

Very new to elasticsearch

Trying to initialize an index from json using the elasticsearch-py api; using this simple json file to just understand how it's working

```
{
  "index": "index_name",
  "body": {
    "aliases": {
      "actions": [
        { "add": { "index": "index_name",  "alias": "alias1" } }
      ]
    },
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "age":    { "type": "integer" },
        "email":  { "type": "keyword"  },
        "name":   { "type": "text"  }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards":   2,
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
      "index.refresh_interval": "120s"
    }
  }
}
```

(read a json file, parse out `index` and `body`) then the important python part
`es.indices.create(index=index, body=body)`

But I'm getting an error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, 'null_pointer_exception', 'fieldName cannot be null')
```

I pulled the mapping and alias example from the ES docs. The python works with a different json file that doesn't have aliases in it. When I remove the aliases from this file I get another error about unsupported mapping parameters so I'm not sure where the problem is, but want to solve the alias issue first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/client/indices.py#L89) of `elasticsearch-py` says, the `body` argument of `indices.create` cannot include any aliases:

> body: The configuration for the index (`settings` and `mappings`)

With that being said, there are [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753607/8160318) in that library that enable you to create aliases.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer says, I failed to read the docs. Posting what ended up working for me for a record

a `config.json` file would look like

```
"index": "index_1",
"aliases": ["alias1", "alias2"],
"body": {
  "mappings": {...},
  "settings": {...}
}
```

And the python

```
_json = json.load(file)
index = _json['index']
aliases = _json['aliases']
body = _json['body']

es.indices.create(index=index, body=body)
if len(aliases) > 0:
       for alias in aliases:
           es.indices.put_alias(index=index, name=alias)
```